Connection is not available in HikariPool-1
We have multiple pods running in AKS cluster in West experiencing intermittent connection timeouts to Azure SQL DB in East(no issue when AKS West is connecting to SQL West). when we capture the tcpdump, it shows no trace of connection attempts to the DB but when everything is working, tcpdump does show the communication between pod and the DB.
2024-04-28 16:56:30,420 [Async-128] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=47)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:86)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:183)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:401)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:676)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:190)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:155)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    ... 32 common frames omitted


Can you adjust minimumIdle and maximumPoolSize to let's say config.setConnectionTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds
config.setMinimumIdle(5);
config.setMaximumPoolSize(20); and see if it solves the issue?

Thanks Arko.. We found the issue, It has to do something with our internal firewall. but still what baffles is why we did not see those connection attempts in our network trace.
